# What is clean ways to handle multiple events in a React component?

Tags: reactjs

I am handling multiple submitting events in parent component when form component submitted, it won't be a problem for me if I handle only a few events but with multiple events like the code below. I feel it's not cleans and too much `await update(data);` be repeated. How can I refactor it code to clean more or is there any other solution?

```
  function ProfilePage() {

        const { update } = useProfile();

        const fullNameHandler = async (data) => {
            try {
                await update(data);
                toastify('Fullname updated!');
            } catch (err) {
                toastify(err);
            }
        };

        const usernameHandler = async (data) => {
            try {
                await update(data);
                toastify('Username updated!');
            } catch (err) {
                toastify(err);
            }
        };

        const passwordHandler = async (data) => {
            try {
                await update(data);
                toastify('Password updated!');
            } catch (err) {
                toastify(err);
            }
        };

        const phonenumberHandler = async (data) => {
            try {
                await update(data);
                toastify('Phone number updated!');
            } catch (err) {
                toastify(err);
            }
        };

        const emailHandler = async (data) => {
            try {
                await update(data);
                toastify('Email updated!');
            } catch (err) {
                toastify(err);
            }
        };

        const formList = [
            {
                component: <Fullname onSubmit={fullNameHandler} />,
            },
            {
                component: <Username onSubmit={usernameHandler} />,
            },
            {
                component: <Password onSubmit={passwordHandler} />,
            },
            {
                component: <PhoneNumber onSubmit={phonenumberHandler} />,
            },
            {
                component: <Email onSubmit={emailHandler} />,
            },
        ];

        return (
           // ...etc...
        )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these functions do that same thing, so you can use a single function to handle all of your inputs. You can also replace the `async`/`await` and `try`/`catch` with `then`/`catch`. Something like this for example:

```
const handleSubmit = (data, inputName) => {
  update(data)
    .then(() => { toastify(`${inputName} updated!`); })
    .catch(toastify)
};
```

And then call the function with the `inputName` parameter:

```
<Fullname onSubmit={data => handleSubmit(data, "Fullname")} />
```

---

Depending on what you're returning, you can also refactor the form list like this:

```
const formList = [
  {
    name: "Fullname",
    component: Fullname
  },
  ...
];
```

And then map:

```
formList.map(({ name, component: Input }) => (
  <Input onSubmit={data => handleSubmit(data, name)} />
));
```

Comment: `onSubmit={data => handleSubmit(data, "Fullname")}` does it affect performance? Should we `handleSubmit` passed as a reference like `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` ?

Comment: @Epple It is a controversial issue. I've never had a performance problem doing this. But I'll let you do your own research on this subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really need coffee right now!

Comment: Oh, I solved this by `onSubmit={handleSubmit.bind(name)}`